# Eclipse CDT c++ project using C headers and doing cross compile

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, cross-compiling

we have an application which is written in c++ and now we are trying to use the same application on the ARM board for which we were provided a toolchain.

So when i do a test c++ project it compiles ok and code on the target is executed perfectly.

As we want to use also some of the functionality of the target (eg display,...), that part is for C, headers are C, libraries are C.

So when i tried including C headers i got a lot conversion errors (eg. Description  invalid conversion from `unsigned int' to`stlv_type'   locaion: tlv_tags.h C/C++ Problem)

For example function generating problems:

```
    static inline
    enum stlv_type _stlv_get_tag_type(unsigned int tag)
    {
        return STLV_GET_TYPE(tag);
    }
```

When creating C project this all works without a problem, but c++ project hundreds of conversion errors.

So i tried to include this headers in extern "C" block without any success, still same problems.

So can somebody help me combine this :) as there is no possiblity to get c++ from the manufacturer and also changing headers is not an option as new platform releases can come at any time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would really like to avoid recreating a lots of pieces in C :S

Comment: Can this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) help?

Comment: I saw the FAQ allready but the problem is that as soon as i include c headers in cpp file it gets compiled with G++ which is more strict and it finds all bunch of errors from inline functions in the c headers. I would like to see that GCC C compiles the headers and CPP uses them :D